# Error Calling the Graph API: Request_DataContractVersionMissing

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm trying to make a POST request to Azure AD GraphAPI to create a user in my AD B2C tenant, but I'm getting the following error

```
"Error Calling the Graph API: 
{  
"odata.error": {"code": "Request_DataContractVersionMissing",
"message": {"lang": "en", 
"value": "The specified api-version is invalid. The value must exactly match a supported version"}
}
```

I do send the version, and based on the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/Azure/Ad/Graph/howto/azure-ad-graph-api-versioning?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#supported-versions) it is supported.

[image]

> Version 1.6
>
> This section lists the changes for Graph API version 1.6.
>
> Graph API version 1.6 introduces the following feature changes:
>
> Added support for **Azure Active Directory B2C local account users**. This involves new properties on the User entity and a new complex type
>   SignInName to support local account sign-in to Azure Active Directory
>   B2C tenants. For more information about Azure Active Directory B2C,
>   see the Azure Active Directory B2C documentation.

[Edit]
submitted json

```
{"accountEnabled":true,"signInNames":[{"type":"userName","value":"ausername"}],"creationType":"LocalAccount","displayName":"A display name","passwordProfile":{"password":"a password","forceChangePasswordNextLogin":true},"passwordPolicies":"policies","country":"MX","givenName":"Fstname","surename":"Lstname","department":"Dpt","jobTitle":"Title","mail":"mail@server.com","otherMails":[],"preferredLanguage":"es-MX"}
```

Any clue on why I'm getting the error?

Comment: can you share the full json submitted? (obiviously changing passwords, etc.)

Comment: @spottedmahn I added the payload to the question

Comment: I tried submitting your json and I got `Invalid value specified for property 'passwordPolicies' of resource 'User'.`

Comment: I removed password policy and I got `Property 'mail' is read-only and cannot be set.`

Comment: I removed mail and I got `One or more property values specified are invalid.`

Comment: I changed `surename` to `surname` and I was able to create a user using the [sample app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet)

Comment: @spottedmahn my problem is before actually being able processing the json payload

Comment: fair enough.  Can you post your `HttpClient` code?  Have you reviewed the sample code and compared it w/ your code?  [Line 161 - 164](https://github.com/AzureADQuickStarts/B2C-GraphAPI-DotNet/blob/master/B2CGraphClient/B2CGraphClient.cs#LC161)

Answer (score 2):

There is something wrong with the api-version query parameter: [Request_DataContractVersionMissing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/howto/azure-ad-graph-api-error-codes-and-error-handling)

> Data contract version parameter is missing. Include api-version as a query parameter with all your requests.

**Doesn't Work**
https://graph.windows.net/ebenefitsdev.onmicrosoft.com/users?api‐version=1.6

I get `Request_DataContractVersionMissing` error when submitting that.

**Does Work**
https://graph.windows.net/ebenefitsdev.onmicrosoft.com/users?api-version=1.6

The difference is the hyphen char.  One is the 'normal' one I typed on my keyboard.  The other [is from here](https://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/dashes.html).

I suspect it is a copy paste problem (I've experienced these in the past).

Comment: Sounds feasible, but I didn't copy pasted the values until I was trying to check if I made a mistake when writing the code

Comment: Out of curiosity,  did you try replacing the hyphen by typing over it and the retrying?

Answer (score 1):

I see one problem: `signInNames` not `signInName`

[image: sample graph create user call]

[Documentation for user entity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/Azure/Ad/Graph/api/entity-and-complex-type-reference#user-entity)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for noticing, I made the change in my code, but it isn't related to the current problem though

Comment: and you made it an array? (not just changing the name)

Answer (score 0):

For future readers, I ran into this issue with 2.0 of graph.windows.net, but it was not the hyphen. It seems this error is also shown if the client ID you used to get a resource token for graph.windows.net is not correct.